# I need to use interrupts using assembly to make an LED light up twice each second

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, interrupt, pic

Implement the assembly-language code necessary to blink an LED on the board twice a second: 250 mS
on / 250 mS off. You pick which LED you’ll be blinking

So we need to write this code but after four hours of work, no one in the class could get anywhere. because we haven't actually learned assembly and the professor is meh.
This is where i am so far and really need help understanding how to finish it or if i'm going in the right direction.

```
#include <PIC16f77a.inc>

TEMP_W      EQU 0X20        ;Temporary location for W during interrupt
TEMP_STATUS EQU 0X21        ;Temporary location for Status during interrupt
TIMERCOUNT  EQU 0X22

__CONFIG    0X0373A     ;This is the control bits for CONFIG register with the
                        ; watchdog timer enabled

ORG     0X0000          ;RESET or WDT reset vector
GOTO    START

ORG     0X0004          ;Regular INT vector`START
CLRF    PORTB           
CLRF    PORTC           
BSF     STATUS,RP0      
MOVLW   0X05            
MOVWF   PIE1                
MOVLW   0X05            
MOVWF   PIR1
MOVLW   0X02
MOVWF   TRISB   
MOVLW   0X04
MOVWF   TRISC
BCF     STATUS, PRO
MOVLW   0X80
MOVWF   INTCON
MOVLW   0X04
MOVWF   CCP1CON
MOVLW   0X0B
MOVWF   CCP1CON,0X04
MOVLW   0X33
MOVWF   T1CON`
```

Comment: you really should lose the "timer", "interrupt", and "led" tags, and mention which architecture this is for instead.

Comment: @MikeNakis These look like PIC instructions to me, and the include would suggest a PIC16f77a.

Comment: *"the professor is meh"* You are paying for this education. Demand better than "meh". Go to office hours and wait for an answer. Or consult your textbook.

Comment: I have him now and can't do anything about it :/

Comment: it says pic in the code, it is a pic.  specifically we can assume a PIC16f77a

Comment: did you leave out the START code?

Comment: Is there specific requirement to do that in assembly ? No longer make sense to use assembly on this type of device unless some very specific timed constraint, in which case you can update to a better device and write it in C, for the 0.1$ more you will spend 95% less time writing your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use timer to make interrupt every 250 ms and then XOR one bit at some port.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <p16f877a.inc>

TEMP_W      EQU 0X20        ;Temporary location for W during interrupt
TEMP_STATUS EQU 0X21        ;Temporary location for Status during interrupt
TIMERCOUNT  EQU 0X22        

__CONFIG    0X373A      ;This is the control bits for CONFIG register with 
the
                        ; watchdog timer enabled

ORG     0X0000          ;RESET or WDT reset vector
GOTO    START

ORG     0X0004          ;Regular INT vector
PUSH
; This stores the current W and STATUS registers in temporary locations during ISRS
MOVWF   TEMP_W
SWAPF   STATUS,W
MOVWF   TEMP_STATUS
BTFSC   PIR1, CCP1IF
GOTO    TIMERINTR
POP
; This restores the original W and STATUS registers before returning to the 
main program
SWAPF   TEMP_STATUS,W
MOVWF   STATUS
SWAPF   TEMP_W,F
SWAPF   TEMP_W,W
RETFIE

TIMERINTR
INCF    TIMERCOUNT,F
BCF     PIR1, CCP1IF
GOTO    POP

START
CLRF    TIMERCOUNT
BCF     INTCON, GIE
CLRF    PORTC
BSF     STATUS,RP0  
MOVLW   0X00
MOVWF   TRISC
BSF     PIE1, CCP1IE
BCF     STATUS, RP0 
BSF     INTCON, PEIE
CLRF    TMR1H
CLRF    TMR1L
MOVLW   0X01
MOVWF   T1CON
MOVLW   0X0B
MOVWF   CCP1CON
MOVLW   0X13
MOVWF   CCPR1H
MOVLW   0X88
MOVWF   CCPR1L
BSF     INTCON, GIE


LOOPTIME
MOVLW   0XFA
XORWF   TIMERCOUNT, W
BTFSC   STATUS, Z
GOTO    OUTPUT

GOTO    LOOPTIME

OUTPUT
MOVLW   0X80
XORWF   PORTC, RC7
CLRF    TIMERCOUNT
GOTO    LOOPTIME

RETURN

END
```